# Jenkins Shared Library - Accessing Git Changeset related info

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Jenkins shared library with bunch of Git repos involved.

- Repo 1: **Jenkins Shared Library repo** which is globally configured in Jenkins.
- Repo 2: **Application code repo** which has the actual application code.
- Repo 3: **Application config repo** which has configuration files for various environments of the application.

The pipeline has various steps like checkout, build, code quality check, unit test, build and deployments.

We use Jenkins provided email template in the shared library to notify the build status. Example code:

```
def nTo = globalNotificationSettings.mail.to ?: ""
def nEnabled = globalNotificationSettings.mail.enabled ?: false
def nSubject = "${nBuildStatus}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} Build #${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
def nBody = '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}'''

if(nTo && nEnabled) {
    emailext body: nBody, \
        subject: nSubject,\
        to: nTo, \
        mimeType : 'text/html'
}
```

The resulting email ends up showing all the changes consolidated into one single table and doesn't show changes per repo. For a quick reference, the email template is available at [Jenkins CI github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template).

Upon further analysis, its obvious that the email extension uses [GitChangeSet object](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitChangeSet.java) and it doesn't seem to have the information on which repo the changeset is coming from.

*Is there a way someone can suggest to get hold of the below info inside Shared Library?*

- **List of changesets being processed by the build at the repo level**
- **I'm not looking for a solution to modify the template. Rather, I need help/guidance on how to access the changeset at a repo level using Jenkins Shared Library. Especially, access the repo info for Jenkins Shared Library which is configured globally in Jenkins.**

Answer (score 0):

I misread your Q initially, and answered wrongly.

I actually have different discussion:
so you have app code, app config and shared lib(s).

### General approach

Each of the above software components, better have its own, dedicated release cycle.

Even though your managers may request you to send ALL the changelogs in 1 build to everybody, this breaks the patterns of separation of concerns/chain of responsibility and decoupling, overloads with irrelevant information (and if you have devs who regularly edit shared lib, this is a serious symptom), also this creates fake accountability (actually fear to touch anything).

So, in terms of who should see each of the changelogs:

1. shared libs should probably have their individual release cycle, i.e. its jobs/builds, with own tests, and changelog. Only the maintainers of it should be informed on problems upon failed changes/regressions (you could take a look at [this project](https://github.com/SAP/jenkins-library) )
2. the app code better be managed by the devs, have its own release cycles, i.e. its own jobs/builds
3. the app configuration is usually extracted into a separate repository b/c it "moves slower" and the changes are not related to app version, usually people avoid changing config often, so it should have its own release cycles as well. TBH, there are cleaner approaches to this, by using a conf service (custom, Vault, etcd, ZK and others), since config changes are rarely done by the developers. They are usually done (in prod envs) by the ops people.

In other words, it seems you are being asked to "solve the wrong problem". But if they insist, this is a very ... strange approach to manage things, and you should be skeptical, and challenge those tasks.

### But you still wanna do it...

However, if you still want to "get the job done", (the job being creating coupling of things people usually separate, i.e. shooting in own foot), you can start trying some/all of:

- explicit `checkout()` call returns an object you can query (for app and config)
- most projects types have repository env variables you can query (comparing PR/MR current hash vs target branch, using repo URL)
- for shared libs, if you have some controls over jenkins configuration, you may **need** to define global variables. for 1 lib to rule them all, you can "extract" both the lib and the version.

Hope this is kind of discussion and "solutioneering" you hoped for.